# Django email sending on Heroku

Tags: python, django, email, heroku

Here is my properties in settings.py file:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'infobot9@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

and here is my send email method:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail 


def sendConfirmEmail(email, instance, code):
    mail_subject = 'Confirmation code {}'.format(code)
    message = render_to_string("msg.html", {
       'user': instance,
       'code': code

    })
    to_email = email
    send_mail(mail_subject, message, 'infobot9@gmail.com', [to_email], 
              fail_silently=False)
```

My Django email sending methods work fine in my local host. After deploying it to Heroku I have allowed the login from unknown devices in my Gmail settings. Gmail does not allow the server login to my account and sends me a message:

spicious login attempt blocked

￼infobot9@gmail.com

Someone tried to log into your account using the password set for them. If it was not you, we recommend that you change your password as soon as possible.



Unknown Device



April 4, 11:39



Near this place: Dublin, Ireland

176.34.163.6 (IP address)

Should I set extra parameters in my `settings.py` file or I need change my Gmail account settings?

Comment: Add `settings.py` to your question, please. also show us your `views.py` code related to sending email

Comment: I've added what you want , In my opinion the trouble could not be in views.py because sending mails from local host works fine, Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I urge you not to use Gmail for sending email in production. It's not designed for that, and as you've discovered there are measures in place to prevent it from being used as a spam relay. Even if you're sending legitimate email, Gmail is going to make things difficult for you.

Instead, use a service that's designed to send mail from hosted applications like SendGrid or Mailgun. These are both [listed among Heroku's addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#email-sms) and both have free starter plans. Pick one and go through its getting sarted guide. Not only will this work better with small volumes of mail, it sets you up nicely for growth.

Answer (score 4):

- [Allow less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)
- [Display Unlock Captcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha)

Comment: thanks! This worked. The email add-ons in heroku require credit card even for the free pack.

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to use Gmail, **@Pierre Monico's**  answer will work. I just wanted to make an edit. After allowing less secure apps to sign in to your account and Display Unlock Capatcha you should still keep two things in mind. **First** be sure to be logged into your browser through the account which you are using in your app to send email so that Capatch should be unlocked for that particular account and the **second thing** is that Google only allows Display Unlock Capatcha for Only **10 minutes** . Thus if you want to use it again and again just keep **Display Unlock Capatcha** page open in your browser and keep it refreshing after sometime.
Also if you have 2 factor authentication enabled then these steps won't work. Those accounts have different procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Above mentioned answers didn't work for me. So here's how I did it. Basically, you need to configure an app password.

1. Go to your Gmail **account**
2. **Security** > in '**Signing in to Google**' section

[image]

3. Turn on **2-Step Verification**
4. **Set app password**

and finally, need to configure `settings.py` or `.env` file(follow's the env),

```
EMAIL_HOST_USER=your_email@gmail.com
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=generated_app_password
```

**Tip**

Using [python-decouple](https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/) makes it much easier to  handle `.env` data