# How to send email with gmail in Django Heroku without using any addon like SendGrid?

Tags: django, email, heroku

Just curious to know if there is any way to send email in Django heroku without using any addon.
As sometimes with add ons there are hidden charges.

The below doc says about the usage of a plugin but it didn't work.

https://blog.heroku.com/tech_sending_email_with_gmail

Are any other ways possible?

Comment: You can use Gmail for testing purposes... [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66078190/8388057)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django email sending on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55569031/django-email-sending-on-heroku)